pip install постоянно выдаёт connection_timeout
с недавнего времени у меня не получается скачивать никакие зависимости с pip. постоянно выдаётся ошибка. Сначала несколько предупреждений с соединением а потом сообщение о том что такой библиотеки нет, хотя он точно есть и соединение с интернетом тоже быстрое :
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002656C64A490>, 'Connection to 192.168.160.237 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/bottle/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002656C64A490>, 'Connection to 192.168.160.237 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/bottle/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000002656C64A490>, 'Connection to 192.168.160.237 timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/bottle/

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bottle (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for bottle

Не знаю насколько это может быть связано но у меня перестали работать такие библиотеки как requests, httpx и прочие подобные одновременно с этим. Пожалуйста помогите.

Ну значит логично предположить, что у вас какие-то проблемы с интернетом

Да и вообще IP-адрес 192.168.160.237 крайне подозрительный — кто-то определённо портит вам интернет

192.168.160.237 - Это ваша локальная сеть, видимо у вас так настроен pip, что репозиторий, где смотреть пакеты, указывает на локальную сеть. И в этой сети либо упал сервер с репозиторием, либо его вообще нет. Нужно точно понять, специально вы выставили такой ip, либо это случайно попала вам в конфиги (~/.pip/pip.conf)

я не понял, что конкретно вы предлагаете делать сейчас

@AbubakrShomirsaidov искать, откуда у вас вылез вот этот вот 192.168.160.237

получается в файле ~/.pip/pip.conf  надо поменять этот ip на ip pip ?

к тому же найти этот файл у меня по этому пути не получается С:/Users/admin/.pip/pip.conf

@AbubakrShomirsaidov надо не менять, а удалять в том месте, где он найдётся (и параллельно с этим выяснить, откуда и почему он вообще взялся)

@andreymal нету у меня такого файла конфигурации там где указано, либо я его не нашел. создал его сам и поменял переменную среды PIP_CONFIG_FILE на путь моего файла. в файле указал index-url равный https://pypi.org/simple. не получилось . до сих пор обращается туда же

@AbubakrShomirsaidov ну значит он где-то в другом месте сидит, ищите

команда python -m pip config debug подскажет где искать

Ошибка все это время была в том что у я использовал прокси-север (192.168.160.237) сам того не замечая. После того как я его выключил все заработало. Выключить можно в Настройки > Главная> Сеть и Интернет> Прокси-сервер
